# How to add delay in css image swap?

Tags: css, image, css-transitions, delay, swap

here's a little css I use to swap images. I use them for little 32px social icons which go from green image to red image. They just swap.

This is the code (using placeholder images):

```css
.soc img:last-child {
  display: none;
}

.soc:hover img:first-child {
  display: none;
}

.soc:hover img:last-child {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a class="soc" href="some-link-here" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/32/32/cats" />
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/32/32/food" />
  </a>
</li>
```

I want to add a little DELAY between the swaps. Like 0.8 or 1.6 seconds.. so the transition between images / color changes are smoother and prettier.

The transition should go like this: Normal Condition to HOVER condition and also, when you just hover and move mouse away, getting back to its normal condition should also have the delay.. well that's what I would love to make.

I tried all kinds of DELAY codes that I was able to google, none worked.. But I also don't want to change the main aforementioned css code which I use, to the ones that will have to have the background-image so that for each icon I gotta make a different 5 line-long css code.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: you could use position + opacity for one of them. or opacity for one and the other as background in the link. you have no transition possible on display. it switches from a value to another because : none to inline cannot be divided in steps

Answer (score 1):

set the right `opacity` starting points

`:first-child` or *green* starts at `1` or **default** value and goes to `0` on `:hover` and `:first-child` or *red* starts at `0` and goes to `1` on `:hover`.

`position:absolute` stacks the objects on top of each other.

then use `transition:opacity ease 1s` for the smooth animation effect. What this property does is it tells the browsers to **fade** the transition from `opacity:0` to `opacity:1` over the duration of `1s`.

adding it to the selector instead of the [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) `:hover` makes the smooth transition occur both when you hover and when you leave the :hover state.

```css
.soc img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transition: opacity ease 1s;
}

.soc img:first-child {
  background: green
}

.soc:hover img:first-child {
  opacity: 0
}

.soc img:last-child {
  opacity: 0;
  background: red
}

.soc:hover img:last-child {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a class="soc" href="some-link-here" target="_blank">
    <img src="/iconslocation/icongreen.png" />
    <img src="/iconslocation/iconred.png" /></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds you want to soften the transition between images by fading from one to the other. I recommend using CSS to [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) opacity over time.

In my example below, I've positioned the second image absolutely, so it's placed directly in front of the first one, and set it to be transparent. Then I fade it in upon hover.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.soc {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.soc img:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.soc:hover img:last-child {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="soc" href="some-link-here" target="_blank">
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/50/50/abstract/1/" />
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/50/50/abstract/2/" /></a>
  </li>  <li>
    <a class="soc" href="some-link-here" target="_blank">
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/50/50/abstract/3/" />
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/50/50/abstract/4/" /></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pure CSS

If we apply the default image as the [`background-image: url()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) of all `a.soc` elements, and give them all [an `:after` pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) holding the second image to show on `:hover` (and optionally (and ideally for accesibility) [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)), we can then [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) the [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) of the `:after` *element* to `1` on user interaction, and at full `opacity` it will cover/hide its parent's `background-image`.

The effect is as expected, but requires no `<img>` markup and is automatically applied by the magic of CSS to every link with `class="soc"`.

```css
.soc,
.soc:after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: url( https://lorempixel.com/32/32/cats );
}
.soc:after {
  opacity: 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: url( https://lorempixel.com/32/32/food );
  transition: opacity 800ms; /* timing can be in seconds or milliseconds */
}
.soc:hover:after,
.soc:focus:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="soc" href="some-link-here" target="_blank"></a></li>
  <li><a class="soc" href="some-other-link-here" target="_blank"></a></li>
  <li><a class="soc" href="another-link-here" target="_blank"></a></li>
</ul>
```